# Find all values of $n$ where $2n^2+7n+3$ is prime.

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Problem: Find all values of $n$ where $2n^2+7n+3$ is prime.

What I know:
All prime numbers are only divided by one and themselves.
To reach a solution, I need to factor the polynomial and equal the binomials to 1.
I did it: $2n+1=1$ and $n+3=1$, and the solutions are $n=0$ and $n=-2$
Then $n=0$ is the only viable solution to produce primes.

What I don't understand:

1. why this works.

Comment: The solution only consists in finding the factorisation $p=2n^2+7n+3=(2n+1)(n+3)$ as you said. Obviously $p$ cannot be prime, because it is then composite for positive integers $n$ by the factorization. For $n=0$ we obtain $p=3$. So I don't understand your questions 1,2,3.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Not that it gives another solution but $n+3=1$ gives $n=-2$ not $-3$.

Comment: @Aig Usually $n$ is a positive integer for this exercise. I suspect that the OP forgot to mention this. Then both $-2$ and $-3$ are not allowed and it doesn't matter. But if all integers are meant, then yes.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, but OP still writes both roots in their reasoning, one of them is wrong.

Comment: Yes, definitely. But there is more than that in question. I don't understand, for example, what "the case of polynomial divided by one" could mean, or "not by itself". In addition, for, say $n=-1$ we would obtain $p=2-7+3=-2$, but usually prime numbers are positive. So I still think one should require $n\in \Bbb N$.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you know, at least vaguely, *what* to do but not *why* it works, so let's go through the reasoning. We are given a polynomial
$$f(n) = 2n^2 + 7n + 3,$$
and we are asked to find all integers $n$ such that $f(n)$ is equal to some prime $p$. Obviously, some trick is needed here: There are infinitely many candidate values of both $n$ and $p$, so we can't just check them all; we need to somehow eliminate infinitely many cases at once. This is where the factorization
$$f(n) = (2n + 1)(n+3)$$
comes into play. Notice that whichever integer $n$ we pick, this lets us express $f(n)$ as a product of two integers. This immediately tells us that $f(n)$ will not be prime in most cases, because there are only four ways of writing a prime $p$ as a product of two integers, those being
$$(\pm 1)\cdot(\pm p) \quad \text{and} \quad (\pm p)\cdot(\pm 1).$$
Thus, if $f(n) = p$, we must have either
$$2n+1 = \pm 1, \qquad n+3 = \pm p$$
or
$$2n+1 = \pm p, \qquad n+3 = \pm1.$$
Notice how in each of these four cases, we have an equation that does not depend on $p$. This is exactly what we want: Even though there are infinitely many primes $p$ that $f(n)$ could potentially be equal to, in every case one of the four equations
$$2n + 1 = 1, \quad 2n + 1 = -1, \quad n + 3 = 1, \quad n + 3 = -1$$
must hold for $f(n)$ to be equal to $p$. We have thus eliminated all values of $n$ except for the solutions to the four equations above, those being $0, -1, -2$ and $-4$ respectively. Well, those are just finitely many cases that we can check by hand:
$$f(0) = 3, \quad f(-1) = -2, \quad f(-2) = -3, \quad f(-4) = 7.$$
We conclude that the only integers $n$ for which $f(n)$ is prime are $0$ and $-4$ (and $-1$ and $-2$ if you allow negative primes).

Comment: This is a clear and concise explanation, thank you for your insight and time @sbares.